# 403 Authentication Error when access Windows Azure Storage Table In Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, xamarin, azure-table-storage

[SAS Token Error IN Xamarin Studio IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3L4W.png)

I have been trying to use xamarin studio in VS2k15 for android app development.the database i use is azure storage table.

so in order to use azure storage table in xamarin you need a SAS( shared access signature) instead of Access key.

I generated the SAS token for the table storage yet this exception(as shown in image)is thrown instead of inserting the data.

[image]

HTTP 403 means the connection is working and accepting request but it is failing in doing the work.

So please help me out. 
P.S the sas token is correctly generated ( cannot be shared for security reasons).

my main activity .cs

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
```

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace App6
{
    [Activity(Label = "Docapp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += async delegate
        {
            appfix temp = new appfix("public", "1001", "2123212", "djnsjd", DateTime.Today, DateTime.UtcNow, "snjdn", 1233, "JDdjvn", "dsjd", 1212, 0);
            string d = await insert(temp);
            TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            tv.Text = d;
        };


    }




    private async Task<string> insert(appfix temp)
    {
        string sas = "https://supapp.table.core.windows.net/request?sv=2015-04-05&tn=request&sig=FlXvYraZKJIz6YQaRpzVBPORPLsyRKMZHQiAVBPkYP0%3D&spr=http%2Chttp&se=2016-04-01T15%3A44%3A49Z&sp=raud";

        string dec;
        try
        {
            // CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(key);

            // CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();


            CloudTable table = new CloudTable(new Uri(sas));
                //tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

            TableOperation insertEntity = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(temp);

            await table.ExecuteAsync(insertEntity);

            dec = "DONE";
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            dec = e.ToString();
        }

        return dec;
    }
```

my appfix class

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
```

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App6
{
    public class appfix : TableEntity
    {
        public string app_no { get; set; }
        public string app_with { get; set; }
        public DateTime app_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime app_time { get; set; }
        public string patient_name { get; set; }
        public int ser_no { get; set; }
        public string patient_rank { get; set; }
        public string patient_aliment { get; set; }
        public int room_no { get; set; }
        public int app_status { get; set; }

```
    public appfix()
    {

    }
    public appfix(string partionkey,string rowkey,string App_no, string App_with, DateTime App_date, DateTime App_time, string Patient_name, int Ser_no, string Patient_rank, string Patient_aliment, int Room_no, int App_status)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partionkey;
        this.RowKey = rowkey;
        this.app_no = App_no;
        this.app_with = App_with;
        this.app_date = App_date;
        this.app_time = App_time;
        this.patient_name = Patient_name;
        this.ser_no = Ser_no;
        this.patient_rank = Patient_rank;
        this.patient_aliment = Patient_aliment;
        this.room_no = Room_no;
        this.app_status = App_status;
    }


}
```

}

my SAS Token

```
https://supapp.table.core.windows.net/request?sv=2015-04-05&tn=request&sig=FlXvYraZKJIz6YQaRpzVBPORPLsyRKMZHQiAVBPkYP0%3D&spr=http%2Chttp&se=2016-04-01T15%3A44%3A49Z&sp=raud
```

Comment: How did you generate SAS Token for table? You can share the SAS token...just replace account name and table name with some other values.

Comment: i generated the SAS TOKEN from azure powershell.  $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "xyz" -StorageAccountKey "XYZ"
Get-AzureStorageTable request -Context $context
$now = Get-Date 
New-AzureStorageTableSASToken -Name request -Permission radu -ExpiryTime $now.AddDays(1.0) -Context $context -FullUri this is how i generated my SAS Token.

Comment: Thank you for sharing details. I tried creating a SAS token for table using PowerShell code you shared above and using that I was able to successfully perform operations. 2 things I want you to check: 1) Account key you used to create the SAS token and 2) Time on the device. Both of these could cause 403 error.

Comment: i use an emulator, so the time on the device is the time on my computer, yes it is correct and account key is the primary access key from the azure storage account right?

Comment: `account key is the primary access key from the azure storage account right` -> That's correct.

Comment: Another thing I noticed in your SAS Token is the presence of `spr` querystring parameter. When I tried creating the SAS token using the code above, it was not there for me. Which version of Azure PowerShell are you using (I am using the latest one installed just yesterday only).

Comment: Which specific Azure storage nuget name and version you're referencing in your project?

Comment: i use azure power shell version : 1.2.3 and i use windowsazure.storage preview version 4.4.1

Comment: Gaurav , did you use the same syntax that i used in the powershell ?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved Issue IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDW2B.png)

> The Issue was solved , Thanks to Gaurav Mantri.

First I updated my Azure Power shell from 1.2.3 to 1.3.0 and updated the WindowsAzure Storage  from 4.4.1 to 5.0.3 preview.

why i used 5.0.3 because Monoandroid 6.0 supports 5.0.3.

The SAS Token had SPR parameter from 1.2.3 windows azure power shell, but in 1.3.0 the spr parameter is not added.

Hence the error was solved.